# Curvature of a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

If we need to find the curvature of a manifold, does that mean we need to find a sectional curvature or a holomorphic sectional curvature in the case of a complex manifold?

Comment: It all depends on the context (there is also Ricci and scalar curvatures).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "curvature of a manifold" by itself. You need to specify your settings.

The curvature is a characteristic of a connection, which is an additional structure that can be defined on a manifold. Depending on the way your data are represented, you choose the method, in which you find the curvature. Usually, you have a parametrization or a coordinate patch, in which you obtain the concrete expressions.

You a right in that knowing the *sectional curvature* [suffices](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/216023/2002) to recover the curvature tensor.

With regards to the *holomorphic sectional curvature*, please refer to the article $[1]$, Proposition 2.2. on p.285 gives the formula expressing the curvature of a nearly Kählerian manifold in terms of the holomorphic sectional curvature.

REFERENCES.

1. **A.Gray**, Nearly Kähler manifolds. J. Differential Geometry, 4, 1970, pp.283–309, http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0267502

Comment: Isn't the Gaussian curvature intrinsic?